# "New Tab with Settings - Basic" Mac Maybe a Dash?

Tags: macos

I am trying to edit the terminal new tab command "New Tab with Settings - Basic" in Terminal on my Mac.

[image]

It doesn't seem to change to anything.  Other commands edit fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to verify your issue, initially I thought it might be there is a hidden character or an unusual type of hyphen, but it isn't I found the strings file and the original string for this menu is:

```
New Window with Profile - %@
```

Testing these options didn't work:

- `New Window with Profile - %@`
- `New Window with Profile - Pro` *My theme is called Pro not Basic*
- `New Window with Profile`

None of these work, but as you said any other item in that menu works so this appears to be an artefact of the fact macOS generates that menu item by concatenating two strings.

There is [a relatively old guide on almost exactly this issue](https://fabiancanas.com/blog/dynamic-menu-item-shortcut) which you could try to follow, but this appears to be a bug and should be reported to Apple: https://radar.apple.com

EDIT: Image of menu item

[image]

Comment: They text should "New Window with Setting - %@"  What is with the inconsistency?  Are you on a newer version?

Comment: I am using macOS 10.13.6 I am not sure if they changed the text or there is another reason but the menu item for me with that shortcut is as described, I've put a screen shot in to show you my system, but anyway, the issue remains the same as best I can tell, maybe someone else has another answer, but looks like a reproducible bug to me.